# How to install and enable at startup a VNC server on Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, vnc

What's the recommended way to install a VNC server on Kubuntu 15.10 x64, and configure it so that it runs at startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution I have found is [RealVNC server](https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/):

1. download, and install. (and buy a license if you need [advanced features](http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/)). Everything can be configured through [command line](https://www.realvnc.com/docs/deployment-script.html#deployment-script) if needed, otherwise it can be configured through GUI as shown below.
2. add RealVNC server to startup:

[image]

[image]

3. Run RealVNC server:

[image]

4. From the RealVNC client, you can connect using your Kubuntu login and password.
5. To change the options:

[image]

[image]

---

I tried KRFB, but [it doesn't save settings](https://askubuntu.com/q/698084/44876).

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced.service
```

this will run it as a daemon at system startup. This daemon is provided with the RealVNC package and is the preferred method.

Comment: This works perfectly in 16.04