# KRFB doesn't save settings

Tags: kubuntu, vnc

I use KRFB 4.14.12 on KUbuntu 15.10 x64. Each time I open it (using `krfb` from terminal) and change the settings, if I close it, the settings are not saved. Why?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is a one-year old bug that still hasn't been fixed:  https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=340411

Answer (score 1):

Either you are on Vivid 15.04 or you are using an outdated version?
see -> http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=KRFB&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

current version in Wily 15.10 is: krfb (4:15.08.2-0ubuntu1) 
This should fix it!

Comment: Thanks, I installed krfb using `apt-get install krfb`

Answer (score 0):

You could place a bug-report @Debian & Launchpad-bugs against that package (haven't found anything likely there). Reference the KDE-bug. Sometimes this speeds up things, to poke the devs from more sides ;-).